# Two forms and buttons bootstrap ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my page. It's in HTML, Bootstrap, and PHP.

I have two forms in the HTML page. First is the contact form, and the other is in a modal and that's the distribution form.

The problem is the data in the distribution form because when I click the button, it sends the contact form only and not the distribution form.

Here is the code.

Distribution form:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 animated slideInUp">
        <form name="sentMessage" action="contact_me.php"  id="contactForm2" novalidate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NOMBRE *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduce tu nombre.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="EMAIL *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduce tu E-mail.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="TELEFONO *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduce tu numero de Telefono.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" style="height:135px;" placeholder="TU MENSAJE *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduce tu mensaje."></textarea>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">UNIRME AL EQUIPO</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Contact form:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form name="sentMessage" action="contact_me.php" id="contactForm" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NOMBRE *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduce tu nombre.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="EMAIL *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduce tu E-mail.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="TELEFONO *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduce tu numero de Telefono.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="TU MENSAJE *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduce tu mensaje."></textarea>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="success"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Mensaje</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript contact_me:

```
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "../contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Tu mensaje ha sido enviado. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because you've got the same id names in both forms. It's important to keep id names unique for each page (as a matter principle and good practice) but if you don't, jQuery grabs the first matching id - which is why only the inputs from the first form are submitted.

I suggest changing the ids of the second form to name_1, email_1, phone_1 and message_1 (to make them unique) and then in the script replace:

```
// get values from FORM
var name = $("input#name").val();
var email = $("input#email").val();
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
var message = $("textarea#message").val();
```

With:

```
// Determine which form is being submitted
var form_0 = $form.attr('id') === 'contactForm2' ? true : false;

// If it's the first form, assign the values from that form,
// otherwise assign the values from the second form
var name = form_0 ? $('#name').val() : $('#name_1').val();
var email = form_0 ? $('#email').val() : $('#email_1').val();
var phone = form_0 ? $('#phone').val() : $('#phone_1').val();
var message = form_0 ? $('#message').val() : $('#message_1').val();
```

and then the correct values are submitted with the appropriate form.

Hope this helps.

If you're not familiar with the 'ternary' operators in the code above - they're just handy shortcuts for if{} else{} statements - check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator